# Golang struct member storing time not holding value

Tags: go, time, struct

I'm trying to store a time in a struct like such

```
type TimeTest struct {
    GoTime time.Time
}
```

I then have an update function that sets GoTime to the current time.

```
func (t TimeTest) Update() {
    fmt.Println(t.GoTime.String())
    t.GoTime = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.GoTime.String())
}
```

GoTime is always 0 at the start of the call to Update. It never holds it's value.

Here is a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jx--aNCAEq) example

Comment: use `*TimeTest` instead of `TimeTest` in function declaration

Comment: Every instance passed as an argument to a function in Go is copied, unless it is passed as a reference. Therefore, you never really modify the original `TimeTest` instance.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a receiving function, you can define it on a value or a pointer.  If you define it on a value (as in your example), a *copy* of the struct is passed to the receiving func, so any updates are lost because that copy is destroyed after the function finishes.  If you define it on a pointer, then the struct itself is passed, so any updates affect the actual copy of the struct the function was called with.

Revised version of your playground example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TimeTest struct {
    GoTime time.Time
}

func (t *TimeTest) Update() {
    fmt.Println(t.GoTime.String())
    t.GoTime = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.GoTime.String())

}

func main() {
    t := TimeTest{}

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        t.Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, a non-pointer called through a method with a pointer receiver has a pointer taken. See http://play.golang.org/p/sZiyU_up8v

Comment: @Vatine corrected.  I mistook my receiver rules to interface rules (literals for a struct with a pointer receiver method don't implement an interface that define that function e.g. http://play.golang.org/p/5eXobphikp).